# Get :first-letter of :hover element with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to get the first letter of an element while in 'hover mode'? This is how it would look - I think - but it's not working in Chrome 10:

```
p:hover:first-letter
```

or

```
p:first-letter:hover
```

Technically (imho) they're not the same. The first takes the first letter of the hovering element. The second takes the entire element if the first letter is hovering. I require the first.

As you can see on http://css4.hotblocks.nl if you 'enable' the CSS blocks, both don't work.

I want only the first letter of the element to color red, when the entire element is in :hover mode. Is it possible **without additional HTML tags**? Thanks.

-- edit I've changed my online example for the better. CSS is now divided in separate `<style>` blocks. Makes for easier turning on and off try-outs.

Conclusion - so far!? - is this: In Firefox 3.6/4 `a:first-letter:hover` does nothing (good) and `a:hover:first-letter` works perfectly (good!). In Chrome 10 `a:first-letter:hover` does nothing (good) and `a:first-letter:hover` breaks the previous CSS 'statement'. (In my example it breaks nothing because it's in a separate `<style>` block.) Which brings us to: once again Google Chrome lags behind Firefox =( --edit

Comment: Your second snippet is invalid. Pseudo-elements like `:first-letter` can only be at the end of the selector. Quote from the CSS spec: "Only one pseudo-element may appear per selector, and if present it must appear after the sequence of simple selectors that represents the subjects of the selector."

Comment: So it's impossible according to the specs? :hover:first-letter is invalid?

Comment: No, that'd be fine: `element:hover:first-letter` **puts** `:first-letter` at the end of the selector.

Comment: But "Only one pseudo-element may appear per selector"... Both `:hover` and `:first-letter` are pseudo-selectors, no? Both don't work in Google Chrome. Is that a Webkit CSS bug? (Did I find a Webkit CSS bug woohoo!?)

Comment: Also `input:required:invalid` MUST be a valid selector, so what's with the "only one pseudo per element" or something?

Comment: @Rudie: :hover, :required and :invalid are pseudo-classes, not pseudo-elements. No such condition is applied to pseudo-classes. Also, the spec notes that the pseudo-element restriction is tentative and may very well be lifted in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've checked your example and I have to say it works, on Fx 3.6.13

```
p:hover:first-letter {
    color: blue
}
```

Only what you have to do, is change color of first letter. Because hover has the same color as text, so you didn't notice any visual change.

Comment: Ah... It does work in Firefox (4 beta 7). It doesn't in Chrome 10. In Chrome 10 it even breaks the previously valid :hover statement. Which is weird. You can't see the red because I added the red to the simple :hover as well. I did that because the other one didn't work anyway =) Thanks for trying though. I should have checked Firefox myself.

Comment: The same is true, it seems, for Chrome 8.0.552.224 (Win XP). Weird.

Comment: Wow this still doesn't work in Chrome 21. And even odder: if this style rule exists, it breaks the entire hover effect/styles in Chrome! http://css4.hotblocks.nl/

Answer (score 4):

Both the `:first-line` and `:first-letter` pseudo-elements are [defined in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-letter) as only applying to **blocks**. The `a` element is inline by default, so `:first-letter` doesn't apply to it unless you change it into a block element. I think Chrome is actually the one working correctly here, though it's inconvenient and I don't know why it didn't occur to the W3C that inline elements can have first letters too.

As an admittedly imperfect workaround, you could add `a {display: inline-block}` or similar in order to get the styling.

Comment: In my example, the :first-letter applies to a `p`: `p:first-letter:hover { color: #f00; }` and `p:hover:first-letter { color: #f00; }` - I'll change it in my question. I guess it is a webkit bug. There are a few